# record id is not searchable in standard salesforce lookup dialog

Tags: lookup, lookup-field, dependent-lookup

I am trying to search related records in a lookup field and I am unable to search using record Id of the record. I tried adding field to search layout. I am able to see the recordId still I am unable to search using recordId.

Comment: Record IDs are internal and not intended for users to use as searchable detail. If you have the ID, there's no need to search for the record. Just use the ID to open the record page directly using something like `https://myorgdomain/theRecordID`.

Comment: We have the Id but we need to search with id and show in search results.

Comment: That's not how it works and makes zero sense. If you have the ID, no search is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has several kinds of indexes. The two types of indexes that are important here are the search index and the database index. The search index keeps track of searchable phrases in a record, such as names, phone numbers, emails, descriptions, and more. Notably, the Id field itself isn't in the search index. The second kind of index, the database index, is how Salesforce finds records quickly based on criteria. Id is one such field, and it is how Salesforce uniquely identifies and locates records without needing to perform a search.

If you really want to search by Id, which certainly could have a legitimate use case, create a custom text field, set it as unique case-sensitive indexed, and set up a flow to auto-populate this field with the ID from the record. By doing this, you're intentionally adding the Id to the search index, and you'll be able to find records using that search.